# How to fetch HTML created via a Forena report and store it as a node?

Tags: rules, log-messages, forena

I'd like to automatically (Rules) copy some HTML into a node . The HTML comes from a Forena report (already as an HTML document), created by the [Forena](https://www.drupal.org/project/forena) module. In the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module I couldn't find anything exactly fitting.

It might be possible to develop a small module that fetches the Forena report (using some of the available Forena hooks) and create a node from it.

But is this the easiest way to go? It feels a bit like a detour, maybe I'm just overlooking some module or feature which can do that task?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have a look to the module "[Feeds](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds)". It's aim is to provide a way to import content (node, term...) from CSV File, XML...

You can also specify interval between two importation. So you won't need rules.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much - that did exactly what I was aiming to do.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Forena](https://www.drupal.org/project/forena) project page: use [Feeds](https://drupal.org/project/feeds) to create nodes using **Forena [data blocks](http://drupal.placeto.be/reports/help.data#datablocks)** and/or **reports**. In other words: Forena can be used as a feeds importer (= to enable Feeds to go read from al kinds of database tables, **external databases**, etc. which Feeds out-of-the-box does not support). And Forena comes with [various hooks](http://drupal.placeto.be/reports/help.development#hooks) to use Forena from within another module.

For more details about Forena, 2 types of documentation are available:

- [Community documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/2041363), which includes a child page [Video demos and tutorials](https://www.drupal.org/node/2360187) containing a link also about [using Forena to import data and reports based on data as drupal nodes](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bg4P747DmE8) (that video even demonstrates the creation of charts, so not just tabular reports).
- Documentation that comes with Forena, which you can access right after install and enable of the module. Checkout the [demo site](http://drupal.placeto.be) for an online example of the current:

  - **Forena documentation** - use the link 'Reporting documentation' or visit relative link /reports/help.
  - **Forena samples** - use the link 'Reporting samples' or visit relative link /reports/samples (these samples are fully functional, so make sure to experiment a bit with it, such as the drill downs available on the SVG Graph sample).

The 7.x-4.x version also includes an amazing (I think) UI for either creating your reports (the WYSIWYG report editor) and/or for creating your SQL queries (the Query Builder).

Here are some variations of the **external databases** part mentioned above:

1. Using a **SQLite** instead of MySQL database: the Forena samples actually get shipped including a (Tiny) SQLite database. Go check it out in the [demo site](http://drupal.placeto.be/reports/samples): the data shown there are data contained in the sampledb, which is in SQLite format.
2. Forena comes with a full suite of [Supported database connections](https://www.drupal.org/node/2041363#dbconnections) ... such as MySQL, MS SQL, Oracle, Postgress or any PDO compliant variation.

**Disclosure**: I'm a co-maintainer of Forena.